# Take Photo in WinJS-WP8.1-App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, photo, winjs

I try to make a photo-app that can read Qr-Codes with the ZXing-Library.
Most parts work but now somehow my LowLagPhotoCapture doesn't return anything useful:

```
var photoProperties = MediaProperties.ImageEncodingProperties.createJpeg();

mediaCaptureMgr.prepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(photoProperties)
.done(function (_lowLagPhotoCapture) {
    lowLagPhotoCapture = _lowLagPhotoCapture;

    lowLagPhotoCapture.captureAsync()
    .done(function (capturedPhoto) {
        ...
```

The MediaCaptureMgr works, I see a preview of the cam on the screen. But now I need to make a photo. The usual PhotoCapture didn't work with JavaScript and so I found this solution.

Somehow the `lowLagPhotoCapture.captureAsync()` crashes saying that lowLagPhotoCapture is empty. lowLagPhotoCapture is defined outside of this class because I need it later. But even if I pass the variable directly to the new method it fails =/

Any ideas what might go wrong with this?

**Edit:**

Okay, after every Async-operation I had a following nameless function and one exitOnError-function that was calles every time. If I remove thatv exitOnError-function out of `.done(complete, error)`, it exits in the same place. But if I set a breakpoint on .captureAsync it goes 1-2 steps further, creates an ImageStream and exits somewhere there. Why the different behaviour with and without the breakpoint?